# Quantisation of electric and magnetic fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics

In the text *Gerry Knight "Introduction to Quantum Optics"* they start with electric and magnetic fields $$E_x(z,t) = \bigg(\frac{2 \omega^2}{V \epsilon_0}\bigg)q(t) \sin(kz)$$ and $$B_y(z,t) = \bigg(\frac{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}{k} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{2 \omega^2}{V \epsilon_0} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\dot{q}(t)\cos(kz).$$

What I don't understand is how they simply identify $q$ and $\dot{q}$ with the position and momentum operators simply because the Hamiltonain is the same form as that of the Harmonic oscillator: $$H = \frac{1}{2} \int dV [\epsilon_0 E_x^{2}(z,t) + \frac{1}{\mu_0}B_y^{2}(z,t)] = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{q}^2 + \omega^2 q^2).$$ Whereas in the equations of electric and magnetic field, $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are not even functions of position or momentum. Also, do we then simply assume that they obey the commutation relation $[\hat{q}, \hat{p}] = i \hbar$ since we have identified them with the position and momentum operators which obey this commutation relation?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you think of $q$ as physical position (what you measure with a ruler) or as a generalized coordinate.  It is the latter.  Perhaps that helps?

Comment: This is the key observation of classical field theory: it is *formally identical* to a chain of notional coupled oscillators, an infinity of them. The *q* s, *at each point in spacetime* represent displacement of each such oscillator from equilibrium. In this language, they [can be easily quantized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization), through [second quantization methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization).

Comment: Related [293088](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293088/why-is-position-considered-a-label-in-classical-field-theory).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I think I understand what you are saying. For say the electric field which I gave, each $z$ becomes just an index of sorts, and for each such index $z$ we model the electric field as we would model, in quantum mechanics, a particle of unit mass in a potential which corresponds to the harmonic oscillator, hence we would in effect have an infinite number of quantum mechanical harmonic oscillators? Is this on the right track?

Comment: Yes, on the right track, but there is a wrinkle... the oscillator at each *z* is coupled to its neighbors (the gradient terms in Maxwell's eqns...) only in *k* space they are decoupled, and then the classical expression is what you are visualizing. It is easier to see this with [phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Harmonic_oscillators_lattice:_phonons), whose index i corresponds to your z, and their k to your k, etc... But, yes, this is the idea of field quantization....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Okay I see. Just one thing...You state that we should model the field as "coupled oscillators" at each point. In the text "Quantum Optics by Gerry Knight", they consider the electric and magnetic fields $$E_x(z,t) = \bigg( \frac{2 \omega^2}{V \epsilon_0} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} q(t) \sin(kz)~~\text{and}~~B_y(z,t) = \bigg( \frac{\mu_o \epsilon_0}{k} \bigg) \bigg( \frac{2 \omega^2}{V \epsilon_0} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \dot{q}(t) \cos(kz)$$ This in turn implies that the classical energy Hamiltonian $H = \frac{1}{2} \int dV [\epsilon_0 E^2_x(z,t) + \frac{1}{\mu_0}B_{y}^2(z,t)]$

Comment: which we can write as $$H = \frac{1}{2}(p^2 + \omega^2 q^2).$$ This just seems like a quantum harmonic oscillator. Would we need to adapt this to incorporate the "coupled" part of the harmonic oscillator model for fields?

Comment: I should think so... They are considering a Single phonon (oscillator normal mode) for fixed k and ω... But the Hamiltonian should superpose an infinity of them, for all such  k and ω... I'm not familiar with the text and its methods... maybe alternate texts could help?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yeah will do. Do you know what the significance is (in a basic sense, since I am just starting to learn about quantum optics) of the fact that the expectation value of the electric field vanishes for all states $| n \rangle$ i.e. $\langle n | \hat{E}_x |n \rangle = 0$ for number states $|n \rangle$? Thanks.

Comment: Sure... The field is linear in a creation and an annihilation operator... so acting on |n> it either raises n or lowers it by 1, so in either case <n| kills the products....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Why is the fact that the fluctuations in the electric field (i.e. $\Delta E_x = \langle (\Delta \hat{E}_x)^2 \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}})$ of *coherent states* are equivalent to that of a vacuum considered a "*classical feature*"? Also, just to confirm, is "vacuum" referring to the state zero number state $| 0 \rangle$ of the harmonic oscillator? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the vacuum is what you say it is. They correspond to the classical-looking oscillation of the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state).

Comment: @CosmasZachos If you have a chance, please have a look [at this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348150/completeness-of-dicke-states).